# Results about the existence of continuous functions in topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Given a topological space, what theorems or results are there that shows the existence of continuous function between that space to another space, or between some subset to an open set of the same space.  For example, we have Invariance of Domain Theorem by Brouwer that indirectly shows existence of continuous injective function by verifying the subset to be open set.  I am curious if you could suggest me similar results like it, regardless of topology or not.

Comment: Don’t know what exactly you’re looking for, but the first thing that pops up in my head is Urysohn’s lemma.

Comment: There's also the Hahn-Banach theorem if you're looking for more functional analysis-ish theorems.

Comment: Invariance of domain is *not* an existence theorem (even "indirectly"); it says that **if** an injective continuous map exists on some space, it is *open*. Not that such a map exists at all?

Comment: For CW complexes there's [obstruction theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obstruction_theory)